# Delete Duplicate Items In SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Migrated from wss 3.0 to sp 2010 I have notice few Lists have been Duplicated twice as shown Below Example of

```
Name     Application   Data    Completed
Test1     Sp2010       March     NO
Test2     Wss3.0       July      Yes
Test2     Wss3.0       July      Yes-------> Should remove this and Below Table 
Test3     Moss2007     June      Yes
Test4     None         Jan       NO
Test4     None         Jan       NO

Name     Application   Data    Completed
Test1     Sp2010       March     NO
Test2     Wss3.0       July      Yes
Test2     Wss3.0       July      Yes
Test3     Moss2007     June      Yes
Test4     None         Jan       NO
Test4     None         Jan       NO
```

if any scripts that would be great!!!

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. What is the problem? What are you asking for? What do the tables above show?

Comment: @teylyn if you see above table its has duplicated twice we need to delete the duplicate table using power shell scripts ...Recently we have migrated from wss3.0 to SharePoint 2010

Comment: What is the data in your post? Is it a SharePoint list? What is the second table in your post? Is that also a SharePoint list? Does that mean that you have two identical lists? Why do you want to remove row 3, but not row 6? Row 6 is also a duplicate. You are not explaining this very well.

Answer (score 1):

[Deleting duplicated](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2013/03/19/powershell-script-to-remove-sharepoint-2010-or-2013-list-duplicates.aspx) items within list have [already been answered in our forum](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78555/identifying-duplicate-items-in-a-large-list-250000-items)

You might have to change few references before running the actual PowerShell script

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate records are pain, no matter how careful we are but over a period of time there is a good chance that duplicate records got entered/imported in sharepoint lists. It is better to remove or merge duplicate from your sharepoint list periodically to keep your data clean and valuable. Out of the box there is not an easy way to do it. With this add-in now you can do it fast and free of cost. Try the add-in, if any issues contact for free support. Check this
https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104381013&sourcecorrid=adc96e23-f032-4606-85ff-0f70cc2f0657&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false